# postgres query partitioned table on current_date

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, database-partitioning

I have a table in postgres with 10 millions of rows and it's partitioned per month by a date column 'created_on'. My problem is that I often need to query such table on a time interval from now back.

However, if try

```
SELECT * 
FROM partitioned_table pt 
WHERE pt.created_on>current_date - '10 days'::INTERVAL
```

this goes over all the partitioned tables.

While if I do the same query with a fixed date string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM partitioned_table pt
WHERE pt.created_on>'2017-11-17 - '10 days'::INTERVAL
```

this goes only over the last partitioned table.

Apparently this happens because current_date is dynamically allocated. Any idea how I can deal with it without the need to specify every time the date?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with partitioning queries.
One of solution is using query param.
For Example:

```
do $$
    declare x json;
    dt date;
    begin
        dt = current_date;
        explain(format json) into x select * from sr_scgenerated where date > dt;
        raise notice '%', x;
    end;
$$
```

> Constraint exclusion only works when the query's WHERE clause contains
>   constants (or externally supplied parameters). For example, a
>   comparison against a non-immutable function such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   cannot be optimized, since the planner cannot know which partition the
>   function value might fall into at run time.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html

or

```
prepare query(date) as 
    select * from sr_scgenerated where date > $1;
   explain analyze execute query(current_date);
deallocate query;
```

from http://www.peterhenell.se/msg/PostgreSQL---Partition-Exclusion-with-nowcurrent_timestampcurrent_date